# Way to test empty length property for null and return a string?

Tags: javascript

I am working through a challenge and trying to set it up so in the event that you pass a string you can determine if there are between 2 and 4 of the letter argument in that string.

My testing of the function worked, however if the matched array is 0 length (in the event there are no matching letters in said string) there is no way to measure the length. I get the error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

I tried using a conditional that would return a string if the length was null. Didn't work, I'm not sure if there is a way to funnel this error into a conditional. Any ideas?

TLDR: Is there a way catch to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` before it throws an error?

```
function countLetters(string, letter) {
    let regex = new RegExp(letter, 'g');
    let matched = string.match(regex);
    if (matched.length == null) {
        return "There are no matching characters.";
    } else {
        let totalLetters = matched.length;
        return (totalLetters >= 2 && totalLetters <= 4)? true : false;
    } 
}
```

```
countLetters('Letter', 'e');
true
```

```
countLetters('Letter', 'r');
false
```

```
countLetters('Letter', 'z');
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the specification of string.match(regex), specifically: "If there were no matches, null is returned." So, you need to handle a null response. You can't avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

If(matched == null || matched.length != 0)

Comment: Zero for length check, not null.

Comment: Yes, match can return null (1st half of your test) but if the return value is not null (2nd half of your test) then it's an array. The length of an array cannot be null.

Comment: Good call really just copied 2nd part without thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try `let matched = string.match(regex) || [];`
2. `matched.length == null` [will always be `false`](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/), so try `matched.length === 0`

Comment: However, in your case you can only check if `matched === null`, it will happen if `length` would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

two changes required to make it work as you need:

1. handle null when no match is found
2. check for length appropriately

corrected code below:

```
function countLetters(string, letter) {
    let regex = new RegExp(letter, 'g');
    let matched = string.match(regex) || [];
    if (matched.length == 0) {
        return "There are no matching characters.";
    } else {
        let totalLetters = matched.length;
        return (totalLetters >= 2 && totalLetters <= 4)? true : false;
    } 
}
```

i would strongly advise that you name your method appropriately. it isn't aligned with the return value or it's type. also, you return either `string` or a `boolean` value. one should refrain from that. return values of the same type irrespective of whether a match is found or otherwise.